# "Have it to say" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ... and I should never **have it to say** that my mother was willing
>   when my father was not.

This sentence is from *Robinson Crusoe*. Does "I should never have it to say" mean "I have never had the possibility to say it" or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Context helps here.  Robbie wants to see the world.  His father wants him to stay at home.  Robbie is determined to go to sea, but he doesn't want to cross his father, so he asks his mother to intervene on behalf of his plans.  Robbie reports that his mother refuses, listing the reasons that his father reasonably opposes the plans to travel.  At the end of this litany, his mother says that she's in agreement with his father and that Robbie

> should never **have it to say** that my mother was willing when my father was not.

That is, Robbie will never be able to say that his parents were of differing minds, that his mother supported his wayfaring plans in the face of his father's refusal to do so.